# Maven issue when building from Atlassian Bamboo

Tags: maven, bamboo

I’m a Maven newbie, and I’m trying to build some software which uses Maven using Bamboo, but can’t get working, anyone here able to help? See below for the error log

```
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR] /D:/Bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/RS-RSR-JOB1/src/main/java/com/confidential1/confidential2/service/mapper/OldCarValueMapper.java:[5,35] cannot find symbol
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25       symbol:   class VweCarExtraInruil
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25       location: package nl.confidential2.web.client.model
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR] /D:/Bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/RS-RSR-JOB1/src/main/java/com/confidential1/confidential2/service/mapper/OldCarValueMapper.java:[31,54] cannot find symbol
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25       symbol:   class VweCarExtraInruil
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25       location: interface com.confidential1.confidential2.service.mapper.OldCarValueMapper
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR] /D:/Bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/RS-RSR-JOB1/src/main/java/com/confidential1/confidential2/service/custom/impl/OldCarValueServiceCustomImpl.java:[11,35] cannot find symbol
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25       symbol:   class VweCarExtraInruil
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25       location: package nl.confidential2.web.client.model
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR] Encountered erroneous type VweCarExtraInruil
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [INFO] 4 errors
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [INFO] Total time: 01:31 min
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-28T15:02:25+02:00
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [INFO] Final Memory: 55M/528M
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:compile (default-compile) on project confidential2services: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR] /D:/Bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/RS-RSR-JOB1/src/main/java/com/confidential1/confidential2/service/mapper/OldCarValueMapper.java:[5,35] cannot find symbol
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR]   symbol:   class VweCarExtraInruil
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR]   location: package nl.confidential2.web.client.model
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR] /D:/Bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/RS-RSR-JOB1/src/main/java/com/confidential1/confidential2/service/mapper/OldCarValueMapper.java:[31,54] cannot find symbol
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR]   symbol:   class VweCarExtraInruil
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR]   location: interface com.confidential1.confidential2.service.mapper.OldCarValueMapper
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR] /D:/Bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/RS-RSR-JOB1/src/main/java/com/confidential1/confidential2/service/custom/impl/OldCarValueServiceCustomImpl.java:[11,35] cannot find symbol
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR]   symbol:   class VweCarExtraInruil
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR]   location: package nl.confidential2.web.client.model
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR] Encountered erroneous type VweCarExtraInruil
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR]
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR]
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Regards,

Guido van Brakel

Answer (score 0):

The build is failing due to compilation errors.  Assuming you did something like:

```
mvn clean install
```

it means maven went thru all of the lifecycle phases up to compile, but got a compilation error in compile (via the compile plugin). https://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.5.0/maven-core/lifecycles.html

The first thing I do in situations like this is check the code out of whatever repo it's in and try to 'clean install' it.

This might happen if the developers didn't check in new files/updates.

Answer (score 0):

Your Maven build shows compilation error :

```
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR] /D:/Bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/RS-RSR-JOB1/src/main/java/com/confidential1/confidential2/service/mapper/OldCarValueMapper.java:[5,35] cannot find symbol
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR]   symbol:   class VweCarExtraInruil
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR]   location: package nl.confidential2.web.client.model
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR] /D:/Bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/RS-RSR-JOB1/src/main/java/com/confidential1/confidential2/service/mapper/OldCarValueMapper.java:[31,54] cannot find symbol
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR]   symbol:   class VweCarExtraInruil
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR]   location: interface com.confidential1.confidential2.service.mapper.OldCarValueMapper
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR] /D:/Bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/RS-RSR-JOB1/src/main/java/com/confidential1/confidential2/service/custom/impl/OldCarValueServiceCustomImpl.java:[11,35] cannot find symbol
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR]   symbol:   class VweCarExtraInruil
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR]   location: package nl.confidential2.web.client.model
build      28-Aug-2018 15:02:25     [ERROR] Encountered erroneous type VweCarExtraInruil
```

It seems the class `VweCarExtraInruil` from the package `nl.confidential2.web.client.model` can't be found in classes `OldCarValueMapper` and `OldCarValueServiceCustomImpl`.

**The usual reasons:**

- The class `nl.confidential2.web.client.model.VweCarExtraInruil` belongs to another dependency which is not available in Maven repository.
- The class `nl.confidential2.web.client.model.VweCarExtraInruil` belongs to a module which is not part of the build.

**Solutions:**

- If it's a dependency issue, ensure the correct dependency is available in the Maven repository.
- If it's a module issue, ensure the module is correctly defined in your `pom.xml`